# Падеж слов после тире в предложении

Tags: падежи

Какой падеж нужен в словах после тире в предложении *На разных этапах развития здравоохранения Чувашской Республики профсоюз включался в решение самых неотложных вопросов с главной целью — эффективная защита интересов, социально-экономических и трудовых прав медицинских работников и создание в коллективах благоприятной рабочей атмосферы.* Склоняюсь к творительному падежу (эффективной защитой интересов), но берет сомнение, и хочется поставить в родительном падеже.

Answer (score 1):

Обязательное согласование в падеже нужно для  обособленных **приложений**, но использование формы Т.п. затрудняет понимание смысла в случае распространенности оборота.

Поэтому можно оформить оборот как **присоединительный**, в этом случае согласование не требуется.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*Очень рельефно это видно в действиях абвера на фронте группировки «Север» **с главной целью** ― Ленинград.* [Василий Ардаматский,(1971)]

*Я поехала первый раз в жизни в США...**с главной целью**: его могила на кладбище под Лос-Анджелесом с боксерскими перчатками на плите и надписью «Don`t try».* [О. М. Герасименко,(2017)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Можно использовать "а именно":

*Другим примером уже созданного фрагмента АИС является программный комплекс по ведению хранилища данных, включающего более 100 показателей развития Челябинской области **по 19 разделам, а именно: производство промышленной продукции,** финансовая работа предприятий, малое предпринимательство и др.* «Вопросы статистики», 2004]

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Почти убедили.

Comment: Примеры звучат как обычные ошибки согласования. Укажите, пожалуйста, у Розенталя или ещё где, что присоединительный оборот не требуется согласовывать.

Comment: А вы, пожалуйста,  укажите, что его надо согласовывать. Я привела в качестве примера предложения, в которых согласование было бы совершенно не у места, так  и китаец не скажет.   Или измените структуру предложения. В этом обороте много падежных форм, так что уже со второго однородного члена смысл сказанного становится неясным.  Грамматика присоединительных конструкций разнообразна: слова, словосочетания, целые предложения.